# Split a variable with lists as values in different variables in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split a variable of a pd dataframe into many. The variable values (row wise) look like this (there are other variables in my df and I want to keep them as they are):

Variable1

```
[('Max'), ('15'), ('Place'), ('FB'), ('27 Aug 2022')]
[('Mily', ), ('Place'), ('Google'), ('22 Aug 2022')]
[('Mishika'), ('Place', ), ('London'), ('22 Aug 2022')]
```

Ideally I want to split Variable1 in as many variables as there are in elements in each list row wise. The resulting frame should be like following:

```
V1      V2    V3     V4               V5
Max     15    Place  FB            27 Aug 2022
Mily    Place Google 22 Aug 2022
Mishika Place London 22 Aug 2022
```

I know the value types in each variable will be a mess, but that is not an issue for me. I have this as of now:

```
for l in df['Variable1'].split('\),\s\('):
    df['var_l'] = l
```

Which is of course not correct.

Comment: Can you show the code which creates Variable1?

Comment: Hi this is secondary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the given dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Variable1': [["(Max)", "(15)", "(Place)", "(FB)", "(27 Aug 2022)"],
                                ["(Mily, )", "(Place)", "(Google)", "(22 Aug 2022)"],
                                ["(Mishika)", "(Place, )", "(London)", "(22 Aug 2022)"]]})
```

##### `>>> print(df)`

[image]

You can use [**`pandas.Series.to_list`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html#pandas-series-to-list) to split a column into multiple ones :

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df['Variable1'].to_list(), columns=['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5'])
out.replace({'\(' : '', '\)' : '', ',': ''}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

##### `>>> print(out)`

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks! This is perfect! Only one small additional Q - is it possible not to specify how many variables to generate? Because I will not know that if I have 5 or more maximum elements.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you want something like this, don't you?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

variable1 = [('Max'), ('15'), ('Place'), ('FB'), ('27 Aug 2022')]
variable2 = [('Mily'), ('Place'), ('Google'), ('22 Aug 2022')]

var1 = np.array([v for v in variable1 ])
var2 = np.array([v for v in variable2 ])

df = pd.DataFrame([var1])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([var2])

df3 = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=0)

print( df3.head() )
```

The output is:

```
     0      1    2            3            4
0   Max     15   Place        FB         27 Aug 2022
0   Mily  Place  Google  22 Aug 2022     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but I accepted the above as that answer takes the data as given and works with that! Appreciate the help though.